# SAPUI5 - what does setting an array for the event handler in the XML do?

Tags: sapui5

I saw in the UI5 "Explored" examples a press event with what looks to be an array:

```
press="[handleViewSettingsDialogFilterBarPressed, views.control.tableViewSettingsDialog]"
```

[Example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.11/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableViewSettingsDialog/code/V.view.xml) on line 25

I understand how normal press events work. What does using an array like this do? I couldn't find documentation on it, so any info on how it works or a link to where it's documented would be very helpful.

Comment: That Toolbar inside the `<infoToolbar>` aggregation is invisible. But even if it's visible, it does nothing when clicked. [In later versions](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableViewSettingsDialog/code/V.view.xml), the toolbar is gone as well which indicates that it was just an overlooked leftover from other developments.. Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

It is a just a shortcut. Maybe it is easier to see this in an example [here](http://jsbin.com/yareju/edit?js,output). Both handlers call the same function in the Controller.

```
sap.ui.jsview("myView.Template", {
  getControllerName: function() {
    return "myView.Template";
  },
  createContent: function(oController) {
    var oBox = new sap.m.HBox({
      items: [
        new sap.m.Button({
          text: 'First',
          press: function(oEvent) {
            oController.press(oEvent);
          }
        }),
        new sap.m.Button({
          text: 'Second',
          press: [oController.press, oController]
        })
      ]
    });
    return oBox;
  }
});

sap.ui.define([
  'jquery.sap.global',
  'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
], function(jQuery, Controller) {
  "use strict";

  var TableController = Controller.extend("myView.Template", {
    press: function(oEvent) {
      alert('press');
    }
  });

  return TableController;

});
//Instantiate View  
var view = sap.ui.view({
  type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
  viewName: "myView.Template"
});
view.placeAt("content");
```

the first item in the array is function to call and the second item is the binding object.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't apply to XML views.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the description of the press Event property under the sap.m.Toolbar [Constructor](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Toolbar.html#constructor):

> Events press : fnListenerFunction or **[fnListenerFunction,
>   oListenerObject]** or [oData, fnListenerFunction, oListenerObject]

Comment: This is what [user3808826 tried to explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039429/5846045). Again, this array syntax works only in JS when it comes to assigning handlers. In XML views however, we can only assign the handler name while `oListenerObject` will be **always** the corresponding controller object. Currently, there is no way to pass an extra `oData` or a different `oListenerObject` in XML views.